# How to compare bold text

Tags: javascript

```
look = document.getElementsByTagName('b')
for(var i=0; i<=look.length; i++) {
  if (look[i].text == "something") { .... }
}
```

I was wondering how can I make  `if (look[i].text == "something") { .... }` work?
Do i need something else then .text, like inner text?

Comment: @tymeJV Next time post it as an answer, would get you some points, even if this question is trivial and a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the bold. You are just trying to grab the text. Use **textContent** to get the text (only text) of element

```
look = document.getElementsByTagName('b')
for(var i=0; i<=look.length; i++) {
  if (look[i].textContent== "something") { alert("inside")}
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7yWE/ 
MDN Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.textContent) (or innerText for IE) :

```
var txt = look[i].textContent || look[i].innerText;
if (txt.trim() === "something") {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.text` use `.innerHTML`  Also for your loop use `i < look.length` rather than `i <= loop.length` as arrays start at index 0, if there are two items in the array they will be indexes 0 and 1.